# Replace unclosed HTML tags by self-closed HTML tags in JSP using regex in Eclipse

Tags: html, regex, eclipse, jsp

Recently I started to refactor a web application project. A lot of HTML tags written in the JSP doesn't respect the standard defined by W3C.
I want to close all  tag not closed.

```
<img style="border:0px;"
     src="target/img/expande.gif"
     alt="Expand target information" > // --> this tag is not closed!
```

So, with this expr I can search all not closed tag: 
 `(?s)<img("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">/])*>` 
What should I do for replace the piece of code with `/>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're using the Eclipse-builtin regex based search&replace on files matching `*.jsp`.

You need to group the parts of interest with a set of parentheses.

```
(?s)(<img("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^'">/])*)(>)
```

In replacement, each group can be identified by `$n` where `n` is the 1-based index of the group. So the `$1` would return you the whole `<img ...` element without `>` (and `$2` would return you the `>` itself; note that `$0` returns the entire match).

So, once grouped the regex like that, this replacement should do:

```
$1/>
```

Note: preview the replacement carefully. Regex and HTML don't necessarily go well together.